# How to fix UITableViewCells cutting off at a fixed height in iOS7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I have a UITableView in my app where each UITableViewCell has a custom view added to its contentView. Now, each such custom view can come at any height and I verified that tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: returns the correct value. The thing is it used to work just fine prior to iOS7. In iOS7 it cuts off every cell's content at the exact same spot, about 40-50 points from the top. I can see using the table view's separator that each cell has the correct height, so it isn't a matter of the cell going beyond its bounds and being clipped. It is clipped while being contained fully inside the cell's bounds.

Anyone has any idea what is the cause of this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Are you adding your custom view to the `self.view` itself or to the `self.contentView` cell's property?

Comment: I'm adding it to cell.contentView in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Comment: Try to log the value that's being send in `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. If your cell content is cut off at the exact same spot, it's more likely that this height is wrong.

Comment: As I said in my original question I did check the values of tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: and they were correct. I also looked at the separators of the table view to see if the height is correct visually and it was also okay. Think that a certain cell should be 100 points high and you can see 100 points difference between the separators that enclose this cell, but out of these 100 points only the top 40 points are occupied by the custom view which should occupy the entire 100.